# Drupal 7: Get all content items attached to all terms in a vocabulary sorted by date

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

Just like the title says. I have a vocabulary with several terms. I'd like to be able to get all items tagged by each of the terms in the vocabulary sorted by date created in one giant list. Is this possible with the built-in taxonomy API or am I going to have to build something custom?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no function/method in Drupal API will get that for you. I believe you will have to make your own.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'items' if you mean nodes then the function you are looking for is taxonomy_select_nodes().
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7

This function returns an array of node ids that match have the term selected.

```
/**
 * Get an array of node id's that match terms in a given vocab.
 * 
 * @param string $vocab_machine_name
 *   The vocabulary machine name.
 * 
 * @return array
 *   An array of node ids.
 */
function _example_get_vocab_nids($vocab_machine_name) {
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($vocab_machine_name);
  if (!$vocabulary) {
    return array();
  }

  $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid);
  if (!$terms) {
    return array();
  }

  $nids = array();
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term_nids = taxonomy_select_nodes($term->tid, FALSE);
    $nids = array_merge($nids, $term_nids);
  }

  return $nids;  
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking at doing the problem is this will have the nodes sorted by the term they are in. It would take another sort function to then sort them by date. I can do this, but I was hoping drupal had something that would do all of this for me more efficiently than me adding another loop to sort by created date.

Comment: Ahh, taxonomy_select_nodes does take a 3rd and 4th parameter, with the 4th being an $order array but because you would be doing this query for each of these terms this would not be as efficient. You could look at the code behind the taxonomy_select_nodes and change the ->condition('tid', $tid) to ->condition('tid', $tids, 'IN') passing an array of term id's (In a seperate function of course). This way you could reduce the queries to a single one but still kind of relying on core functionality for the other items.